# Stalled cycles due to fldz instruction

Tags: c++, assembly, floating-point, profiling, perf

I am trying to interpret some perf results on a Xeon x5675 processor.  I have a program where a large percentage of the cycles are stalls (from `perf stat`).  Using `perf record -e stalled-cycles-frontend,stalled-cycles-backend`, I found that *both* front and backend stalls are in large part due to a single `fldz` instruction.

This instruction is inside of a loop that does the following (from `objdump -D -S objectfile.o`):

```
// function is inlined by compiler
void doit(double someval, float cutoff) {
    double other = lookupOther(); // just a memory access

    if (someval && other - someval > cutoff) // fldz instruction is from the 'someval != 0' check
    ...
}
```

I first thought there might be resource contention for the FPU due to hyperthreading (multiple instances of the process run continuously on the same machine), so I tied each instance to a core using `taskset` and ensured that no other process was using the hyperthreaded companion core of my profiled process' core (I cannot reboot the machine to set `isolcpus` boot parameter).  I verified in `top` that nothing FPU-heavy was using the core (just interrupts and a bash shell).  Unfortunately I am getting nearly identical profiling results.

I similarly checked the `LLC-load/store-misses` and `L1-dcache-load/store-misses`; both these showed the same instruction as a hotspot.  Strangely, `L1-icache-load-misses` does *not* show the `fldz` instruction at all.

My final guess was that the instruction stalls were due to branch misprediction, but recording `branch-misses` also does not show the `fldz` instruction.

How else can I interpret both instruction and data stalls due to `fldz`?

**Edit**: clarified that variables are lookups instead of calculations.

Comment: Do any of the miss reports show instructions near the fldz?

Comment: This looks like a complicated computation, hence the backend-stalls (data dependency for the comparison) and the frontend-stalls (hard to predict the branch outcome).
Do you know how long is `comeputeSomeval` taking compared to the other functions?

Comment: @Leeor: No, those are just there to show the types.  They are definitely not complex calculations, just memory lookups really.  I have updated the question to reflect.  Also, I explicitly measured `branch-misses` and found that they were not occurring anywhere near this instruction.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: I can see nearby instructions, but `perf report` does not count them as contributing to the instruction/data stalls.

Comment: Attributing time to individual instructions is very tricky in modern processors, because there is so much happening at the same time. I would interpret the time peak in the perf report as meaning that there is a big stall around when the fldz is executing, not that the stall is caused by it.

Comment: Why the hell is your program using the obsolete x87 FPU on a modern x86-64 cpu? Also, if your program is *only* checking that number for zero, you can simply test for integer zero, it's the same bit-sequence.

Comment: @EOF: I have no idea what that means.  We are using an ancient compiler (gcc 4.2.1), which may provide your answer.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: that would make sense.  Nearby are some memory accesses for floats that are data members of objects stored in a list.  When you say "nearby", how nearby is nearby?

Comment: @JRG: AFAIK, that compiler should be able to generate code for x86-64, which implies `sse/sse2` vector floating-point. Try compiling with `-mfpmath=sse`.